# C: Prevent passed function parameter modification?

Tags: c

*Disclaimer: I don't have a lot of experience with C, I've only been using it for around a week now*

*Disclaimer 2: The code included in this post has nothing to do with removing spaces from a string and is only used to demonstrate the issue I was encountering*

I'm having an issue with creating a function to remove all spaces from a string. While there are countless examples on the internet, I can't seem to find one that, instead of modifying the passed parameter, returns a completely new value that can be then assigned to it's own variable. (Maybe I'm just using C wrong)

```
char *rep(char s[])
{
    s[5] = '\0';

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "this is a test";
    char *b = rep(a);

    printf("%s\n", b);
    printf("%s a", a);

    return 0;
}
```

My output returns the same value when printing a and b, but I want to be able to not modify the value of a, and instead assign it to a new variable.

Comment: You'll need to allocate a new string (using `malloc()`) to hold it, and `free()` it afterwards. That's how C works.

Comment: allocate some space for the return value (malloc), copy the content you need from s (memcpy).

Comment: Or, create a second array on the stack, copy into it, then modify that. Regardless, you need to manually make your own copy.

Comment: Study (in this order): arrays, pointers, strings, functions, dynamic memory allocation. Now each of those things may just correspond to chapters in many C programming books.

Comment: @xcdev Maybe you should take a look at the comments...

Comment: @PalLaden I've looked at all relevant the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are passed by reference in C not by the value.

You need to duplicate it into a new string and modify the duplicated string. You can use strdup function. Remember to check if it was successful.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *rep(char s[])
{
    char *n = strdup(s);
    if(n) n[5] = '\0';

    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[] = "this is a test";
    char *b = rep(a);

    printf("%s\n", b ? b : "strdup failed");
    printf("%s a", a);

    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I recall `strdup` is non-standard. Further there's no `free` and finally `n[5]` maybe out of bounds

Comment: @4386427 the code is illustrative only (originated form the OP question) and we do not consider out of bounds accesses. BTW in this example, it is not possible.

Comment: [`strdup()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup) is pretty new. This might not work on old compilers.

Comment: `if (n && strlen(n) >= 5)) n[5] = '\0';` or a bit faster  `if (n && n[0] != '\0' && n[1] != '\0' && n[2] != '\0' && n[3] != '\0' && n[4] != '\0' &&) n[5] = '\0';`

Comment: @0___________ We should always care about out of bounds access.

Comment: @4386427 in real code. And ***` or a bit faster`*** part sounds hilarious. BTW none of your code snippets prevents out of bounds access. It can be only done by passing another parameter.

Comment: @0___________ both prevent out of bounds access as the if-condition will be false for short strings. In other words - `n[5] = '\0';` will not be executed on short strings

Comment: @0___________ The function is to be called with a string which ensures a zero-termination

Answer (score 2):

First a few about your code. Since `b` is a pointer pointing to `a` any changes to to `a` will also be visible through `b`. So as you say - you need a copy.

In C there is no way to return an array from a function. Instead you can allocate some dynamic memory which can be used just like an array and return a pointer to the dynamic memory.

Like:

```
// This function must be called with a valid C-style string
// The function will return a dynamic allocated string
// with a copy of the first 5 characters of the input.
// If the input is shorter than 5 characters, all characters is copied.
char* rep(char s[])
{
    char* res = calloc(6, 1);  // Allocate the maximu size, i.e. 6 chars
                               // The "wasted" memory in case of short
                               // input strings are little compared to
                               // the overhead of dynamic allocation
                               // so it doesn't matter with a little
                               // over-allocation
    assert(res != NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 && s[i] != '\0'; ++i) 
    {
        res[i] = s[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Remember that the caller must `free` the returned pointer when it isn't used anymore.

Comment: I agree with you that the OOB check should be contained in a proper SO answer. I would just use `strncpy();` where for n I would use the minimum between `5` and `strlen(s);`. Before that I would `calloc(n+1, 1)`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Your approach is also fine. But the downside is that `strlen` can be slow if the input string is very long, e.g. 100.000 chars. Therefore I decide to do the copy char-by-char

Answer (score 0):

## Using malloc

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* rep(char s[])
{
    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != 0 ; i++) {
        ++l;
    }//determines the length of the string
    char* str = (char*)malloc(l*sizeof(char));//allocates memory for the new string
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != 0 ; i++) {
        str[i] = s[i];
    }//copies contents of string s to str
    
    //your operations below
    str[5] = '\0';//anything you do here is your sole responsibility
    //your operations above
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "this is a test";
    char *b = rep(a);
    printf("%s\n", b);
    free(b);//remember to free the memory after use
    printf("%s a", a);
    return 0;
}
```

I have not used any library functions from `string.h`.

Comment: have you heard about strcpy?

Comment: Please take some time to consider these cases: 1) char a[] = "ab"; and 2) char a[] = "abcd";

Comment: @4386427 the code is ilustrative and we do not consider out of bonds accesses here.

Comment: @4386427 I did exactly what the question asked. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @PalLaden Why do you copy all of `s` into `str` and then truncate it!? The for-loop should never copy more than 5 chars

Comment: @0___________ `strcpy` is a bad idea. Maybe `strncpy` could be used but not `strcpy`

Comment: @4386427 how can you know the size of the memory referenced by the `s` with this function prototype? you simply cant use `strncpy`

Comment: @0___________ Using e.g. `strlen` you can find the length. For short string you the copy all the string and for string being 5 or more, you only copy the first 5 chars.

Comment: @PalLaden and the `malloc` should never `malloc` more than 6 chars

Comment: @4386427 wha if the `s` does not reference the valid string? What if  `char a[256] = "aa";`? `a[5]=0;` will be a legitimate write. As I wrote before your methods make no sense at all

Comment: @0___________ By contract such functions are UB if not called with a valid string. Just like all standard string functions, e.g. `strcpy`. And for your `char a[256] = "aa";` is doesn't hut to skip the `a[5]=0;` as `a[3]` already holds the termination

Comment: @4386427 by contract caller has to pass the reference to array which is long enough. We check for errors because we breach contracts.

Comment: Don't cast the result of a call to `malloc()`.